# can not train a deep auto-encoder neuron network well

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

I try to train a neuron network as follow, but can not get good result.
the dataset is mnist. you can see loss is not low,
I try different optimizer( Adagrad, SGD, Adam), different learning rate, doesn't work.
is there way to get better result?

the log is

Epoch 75/100 
60000/60000 [==============================] - 271s - loss: 1191.9388
Epoch 76/100
60000/60000 [==============================] - 232s - loss: 1191.7773
Epoch 77/100
60000/60000 [==============================] - 232s - loss: 1191.6079
Epoch 78/100
60000/60000 [==============================] - 207s - loss: 1191.4511
Epoch 79/100
60000/60000 [==============================] - 205s - loss: 1191.2935
Epoch 80/100
60000/60000 [==============================] - 223s - loss: 1191.1510
Epoch 81/100
60000/60000 [==============================] - 243s - loss: 1191.0016
Epoch 82/100
60000/60000 [==============================] - 224s - loss: 1190.8688
Epoch 83/100
60000/60000 [==============================] - 214s - loss: 1190.7299
Epoch 84/100
60000/60000 [==============================] - 283s - loss: 1190.5929
Epoch 85/100
60000/60000 [==============================] - 243s - loss: 1190.4609

[image: auto-encoder network structure]

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import load_model, Model, Sequential
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Activation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import keras
import theano
import os

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
nx_train=np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0],x_train.shape[1]*x_train.shape[2]))

if os.path.isfile('deep_auto_encoder_example.h5'):
    model=load_model('deep_auto_encoder_example.h5')
    inputs = model.inputs[0]
    encoded = model.layers[4].output
else:
    inputs = Input(shape=(784,))
    en_hid1 = Dense(1000, activation='linear')(inputs)
    en_hid2 = Dense(500, activation='linear')(en_hid1)
    en_hid3 = Dense(250, activation='linear')(en_hid2)
    encoded = Dense(30, activation='linear')(en_hid3)
    de_hid1 = Dense(250, activation='linear')(encoded)
    de_hid2 = Dense(500, activation='linear')(de_hid1)
    de_hid3 = Dense(1000, activation='linear')(de_hid2)
    decoded = Dense(784)(de_hid3)
    model = Model(input=inputs, output=decoded)
    sgd = keras.optimizers.Adagrad(lr=0.0001)
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=sgd)
    model.fit(nx_train, nx_train, batch_size=32, nb_epoch=100)
    model.save('deep_auto_encoder_example.h5')

import scipy.misc
from PIL import Image
para_imnum = 10
imarray=model.predict(nx_train[0:para_imnum**2])
ll = []
for i in range(para_imnum**2):
    im = np.reshape(imarray[i],(28,28))
    if i ==0:
        ll = im
    else:
        ll = np.concatenate((ll,im), axis=1)

lh = []
ims = np.reshape(np.transpose(ll),(para_imnum,28*para_imnum,28))
for i in range(para_imnum):
    if i==0:
        lh = np.transpose(ims[i])
    else:
        lh = np.concatenate((lh,np.transpose(ims[i])),axis=0) 

scipy.misc.imsave('deep_auto_encoder_predict.jpg',lh)


encoder = Model(input=inputs, output=encoded)

import tsne
cor_xy = tsne.tsne(encoder.predict(nx_train[:2000])/1000)
cor_x =[]
cor_y =[]
point_c = []
c = np.arange(10)/10.
for i in range(cor_xy.shape[0]):
    cor_x.append(cor_xy[i][0])
    cor_y.append(cor_xy[i][1])
    point_c.append(c[y_train[i]])
#print(pp)
plt.scatter(cor_x, cor_y, c=point_c)
plt.savefig('deep_tsne')

#plt.show()
```

Comment: You might try using `relu` as activation function, because a network with all linear activation ends up being a linear transformation, which doesn't work well with image. Additionally, try use `binary_crossentropy` as the loss function.

Comment: @Jason, I did what you suggested, but did not improve the result ,  even worse.

Answer (score 0):

Know its late but just in case sb comes back. Try different nonlinearity and different optimizer. Also you can start with fewer layers first then start adding more layer after the simple one is trained. you can also freeze the weights of the trained layer in such settings.